# Ember Component: Animation effect while showing the component

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a Ember Component defined, and when I click on a button I am toggling a property which shows the component.

I need to apply some animation effect when showing the component. Animation effects like SlideDown/SlideUp.

I am not sure how to give animation effect to the Ember Components.

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <button {{action 'showDiv'}}>Show Div</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    {{#if showDiv}}
        {{temp-animation}}
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

App.js:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions:{
    showDiv: function(){
        this.controller.toggleProperty('showDiv');
    }
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    showDiv:false
});
```

JSBIn [Demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gaden/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take advantage of the `didInsertElement` event on the component.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsbin.com/poxupuso/1/edit

I refactored your code a little bit. Pulled the actions out of the route and put them into the the controller.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  showDiv:false,
  actions:{
    showDiv: function(){
      this.toggleProperty('showDiv');
    }
  }
}); 

App.TempAnimationComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function () {
    this.$('.animdiv').slideDown();
  }
});
```

I also added `display:none` to `.animdiv` so that we can animate from a hidden state.

```
.animdiv{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
}
```

This is obviously the most basic example. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthew Blancarte.

Comment: Happy to help! There are quite a few useful component hooks available if you want to animate in certain situations. Just poke around in the documentation and you'll figure it out: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html Down near the bottom is where the good stuff is. In case you ever need it, you can also animate on transition with an observer that watches `controllers.application.currentPath` You can come up with some pretty sick animations if you combine all that stuff.

Comment: You could use `this.$().slideDown()` to hide and show the actual component element instead of its child - no need for the extra div.

Comment: @DuncanWalker Yep, you could use this same pattern on the component itself. You'd need to specify a classname from within the extension so that you could set a default hidden class to it, but yeah. Same deal. At this point it would be a waste of time for OP to refactor. No gain in performance or readability.

Comment: True! Though it could make the HTML/CSS cleaner in many situations. Just thought I'd note it anyway.